# iText basefont mingliu.ttc italic cannot work

Tags: itext

I want to show text in mingliu font style italic, using the following code but fail, the output is still standard style, not italic (I am using iText 2).

```
PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
..................
String ttfPath = null;
ttfPath = BaseSection.class.getResource("/WEB-INF/lib/mingliu.ttc").getPath();
try{
   this.bfi = BaseFont.createFont(ttfPath+",0,Italic", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
   cb.setFontAndSize(bfi, 8);
   ..........
    cb.showText(companyText);
 }
```

Any method to show the mingliu text in italic style using BaseFont.createFont?
Thanks.

Comment: Your code isn't supposed to work. As for using iText 2, please read  the answer to the StackOverflow question [Can iText 2.1.7 or earlier can be used commercially?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25696851/can-itext-2-1-7-or-earlier-can-be-used-commercially) There is an answer to your question, but it's irrelevant as you shouldn't use iText 2.

Comment: Then how to make the code work?

Comment: As you can read in the [FAQ](http://itextpdf.com/salesfaq), iText 2 is no longer supported. Why are you still using it? Are you starting a new project built on iText 2? Please don't.

Comment: maintain a very old project using iText2, need add a footer using Italic style of MingLiu font.

Comment: Very old projects need maintenance. Upgrading to the newest iText may be a good idea. Also: the answer to your question can be found in [The Best iText Questions on StackOverflow](https://leanpub.com/itext_so) so why don't you start reading...

Comment: I have read the ebook and search the keyword "Italic", but seem no mention how to do mingliu italic using basefont, where is it mentioned?

Comment: I'm sorry, but it was one of my New Year's resolutions not to answer questions of people who insist on using iText 2.

Comment: not my insist, but I have no power to change what technology my company is using.

Comment: But you can report the problem: maintaining the project means upgrading. If you don't inform the "powers that be", they'll never know and your job will remain difficult due to using iText 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the following can solve my problem

```
PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
cb.saveState(); 
String ttfPath = BaseSection.class.getResource("/WEB-INF/lib/mingliu.ttc").getPath();
bf = BaseFont.createFont(ttfPath+",0", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
String companyText = "abc";
Font font = new Font(bf, 8, Font.ITALIC);
Chunk chunk = new Chunk(companyTextC, font);
Phrase phrase = new Phrase(chunk);
ColumnText.showTextAligned(cb, Element.ALIGN_RIGHT, phrase, document.right(), 1, 0);
cb.restoreState();
```

Hope this can help others with similar problem.